# Is it possible to use ember data fixture adapter with a single object instead of an array?

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-data, testng, fixtures

When using ember-data with the fixture adapter, it seems to only work when your `FIXTURES` is an array. What if I have a single application-wide object that I want to use for testing?

This does not work:

```
App.Something = DS.Model.extend({
    prop1: DS.attr('string'),
    prop2: DS.attr('boolean'),
});

App.Something.FIXTURES = {
    id: 1,
    prop1: 'value',
    prop2: false
};
```

...it throws a "undefined is not a function" error when trying to invoke `.map` on the fixtures object (which makes sense, because it is not an array).

Only this works, but I want the controller in question to be an object controller, not an array controller:

```
App.Something = DS.Model.extend({
    prop1: DS.attr('string'),
    prop2: DS.attr('boolean'),
});

App.Something.FIXTURES = [{ // wrap in array
    id: 1,
    prop1: 'value',
    prop2: false
}]; // wrap in array
```

Is there no way to have a single fixture?

Answer (score 0):

this.store.find method expects an array for what I understand. The way I get a single fixture to work is by returning App.Something.FIXTURES in the route instead of using this.store.find("something").